# Sorting elements based on condition

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="album">
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pseudo Code:

```
in each album
    each listing 
        hidden = find ('.btn.hidden')
    remove and append (move) all hidden to the bottom
```

I'm not sure how to remove elements and then append?

Comment: Use `append()`. It will transparently remove the elements from their original positions in the DOM.

Comment: What do you mean by "to the bottom"?

Comment: Do you want to move the `.btn.hidden` elements to the bottom of their `.listing`, or the `.album` or do you want to move the parent `.listing` itself? Seeing your expected output and some code you've written yourself here would help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan @Terry Want to move hidden elements to the bottom of non-hidden. So they're still inside the `album` just at the bottom

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi again pseudo code :)

Comment: Why the downvotes? I didn't know `append` removed the elements automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try something like:

```
$('.album').each(function(){
   $(this).append( $(this).find('.listing').has('.btn.hidden') );    
});
```

append() will automatically remove

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4p0trfw/)**

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you could have multiple albums on the page, and that you want to preserve the album this item belongs to:

```js
$('.album').append(function(){
   return  $('.listing',this).has('.btn.hidden');    
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  background-color:red
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album">
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button (hidden1)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
   <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button (hidden2)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="album">
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button (hidden3)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
   <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button (hidden4)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that if there are multiple instances of each button, you would want to preserve the order. Given the following markup:

```
<div class="album">
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button Hidden 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button Hidden 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn hidden">Button Hidden 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use:

```
$('.album').each(function() {
    $('.listing').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('.btn.hidden').length > 0) $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.album'));
    });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pkdw1qp2/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.album .listing').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.btn.hidden').appendTo($(this));        
});
```

I'm not sure where do you need to move, on the end of `.listing`?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q0pq196/)